# Using Lite Version of Entity in nHibernate Relations?

Tags: performance, nhibernate, hibernate, castle-activerecord

Is it a good idea to create a lighter version of an Entity in some cases just for performance reason pointing to same table but with fewer columns mapped. E.g If I have a Contact Table which has 50 Columns and in few of the related entities I might be interested in FirstName and LastName property is it a good idea to create a lightweight version of Contact table. E.g.

```
public class ContactLite
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}

}
```

Also is it possible to map multiple classes to same table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a good idea. Instead, always map the full class and create smaller ones that you can project on using `Transformers.AliasToBean` or LINQ.

An example of the latter:

```
var lightContacts = (from contact in session.Linq<Contact>()
                     where contact.Country = "Argentina"
                     select new LightContact
                            {
                                Id = contact.Id
                                FirstName = contact.FirstName,
                                LastName = contact.LastName
                            })
                    .ToList();
```

This will only select those three fields from the DB, even when filtering by a different one.

It's worth noting that, with LINQ, you could also use an anonymous type to select any projection you want without creating additional types or mappings.

Comment: I want to use mainly for Relations. If I have a Many-2-One relation then I don't want it to load 50 Columns.

Comment: Still the same case.

By default, many-to-ones are loaded as proxies using the primary key, and they won't be loaded at all if you exclude them like above.

Comment: Unfortunately I am on nHibernate 1.2 with WCF and Lazy loading is not an option with me. So everything is eager fetched.

Comment: 1.2 is old and totally unsupported at this point. You should really, really consider upgrading.

Also, WCF shouldn't have anything to do with the decision; if it does, you are working at the wrong layer.

Answer (score 5):

Don't map multiple classes to the same table. I tried this once and though it worked for what I was doing, I'm sure it would have bitten me later. It's better to use projections to populate the "light" classes.

Answer (score 1):

I used this approach for handling an Entity without a BLOB-field (just for handling relations etc).

I had some issues regarding Implicit polymorphism, meaning I had this setup:

public class ImageWithData : Image

The inheritance made NHibernate load an ImageWithData in a second roundtrip every time I resolved an Image directly (not when related with BelongsTo or HasMany).

There is an option in NHibernate to disable this behaviour, called polymorphism="explicit" which you specify on your base-class (in my case, Image).

If it will be bad design in your case, I don't know, it all depends on why you need to lighten your entities.